# CloudTasks not scaling GAE Backend instances

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I was searching for a solution which would allow me to run tasks up to 24h long. The combination of Cloud Tasks and multiple AppEngine Backend instances seemed like a perfect way to go.

As the tasks are long running, I would like to scale to **max_instances** as fast as possible. But I am having trouble to do so.

Here is my **app.yaml**

```
service: slow
runtime: python37
# --timeout=90000 (25h) -> AppEngine Backend Instance should raise TimeoutExceededError after 24h
entrypoint: gunicorn main:app --workers 1 --timeout=90000
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 15
```

Here is a [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBXgt.png) of my Cloud Task Queue configuration.

My issue is that the tasks from Cloud Task Queue are not spawning new instances as I would expect (eg. 15 max_concurrent_tasks in queue settings should spawn 15 backend instances).
I somehow managed to overcome this issue by aggressively increasing **max_concurrent_tasks** in the queue configuration (200 max_concurrent_tasks will spawn 15 backend instances).
Unfortunately, as the number of tasks in queue decreases, the backend instances will start terminating.

**Now, there is 8 tasks left in queue (out of several hundreds) and only 1 backend instance , which is running 1 task only. I cannot trigger starting additional instances even by clicking on the "RUN TASK" button in CloudTask web UI.**

Has anyone of you came across similar issue?
Do you have any hint why this might be happening?
Why doesn't cloud task hit **/_ah/start** endpoint to spin up a new instance to run on?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if basic scaling is good idea. According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed#apps_with_basic_scaling):

> If you use basic scaling, App Engine attempts to keep your cost low,
> even though that may result in higher latency as the volume of
> incoming requests increases

It seems that automatic scaling will be better idea. If you take a look at the same document you can find:

> If you use automatic scaling, each instance in your app has its own
> queue for incoming requests. Before the queues become long enough to
> have a noticeable effect on your app's latency, App Engine
> automatically creates one or more new instances to handle the
> increasing load.
>
> You can configure the settings for automatic scaling to achieve a
> trade-off between the performance you want and the cost you can incur.

The documentation mentions 3 settings that can be used:

1. Target CPU Utilization
2. Target Throughput Utilization
3. Max Concurrent Requests

I think you should be able find the configuration that will serve you the best with those 3.